Create a visual diff between two images and overlay it on one of these using imagemagick
I have two images (of a schematic) and I want to highlight the differences on one of them:


Using imagemagick I can create the visual diff and I can also overlay it over the second image:
compare schematic.png schematic-new.png -compose src diff.png
composite -blend 35% diff.png schematic-new.png schematic_diff.png

This provides almost what I want, but the parts in the diff-image that are the same are not fully transparent, but have a semi-transparent grayish color. Also the blend is not the right thing to do, as it adds transparency to the base image as well.


So: How can I create the diff image so that the non-diff parts are fully transparent and how to overlay it correctly on the base image (maybe even with custom transparency)?

Your command doesn't generate that diff output you showed. Which IM version are you using? Unless you added some fuzz which produced similar output for me. Anyways, for the 1st problem try using -lowlight-color none. For the 2nd -watermark instead of blend.

That is probably because imgur does some image processing on the images

Imgur no longer exists here and it didn't tamper quality IIRC, the new SE thing might indeed

To avoid some non-diff color from appearing on the diff image, add -lowlight-color none option that specifically sets the color to fully transparent:
magick compare schematic.png schematic-new.png -compose src -lowlight-color none diff.png

As for overlaying the images, you basically used the only predefined composition mode that mixes transparencies like that. E.g. both -dissolve and -watermark work much better in terms of putting a layer over another with transparency. This looks quite good to me and I think is close to what you desire:
magick composite -dissolve 30 diff.png schematic-new.png schematic_diff.png

Lower the 30 percentage if needed.

Thanks a lot! Exactly what I was searching for. Imagemagick can be pretty overwhelming when you are not too deep into it...
